# Converting existing Flutter Java Android project to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I have an existing Flutter project that was created with Android Java set.
I tried removing my `android` directory and running `flutter create -a kotlin .`. App fails to run and error says it is still expecting `main/java/com/myApp/MainActivity.java` even though the `main/kotlin/com/myApp/MainActivity.kt` was generated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your android `app` level, check your `build.gradle` and make sure you have this

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    ...
}
```

you can change the dir path to your `MainActivity.kt` placed